# How to make a GPS transportation app?

Tags: algorithm, gps, transport

I live in Split,Croatia, and a city bus company recently accuired a new piece of software, and what it does is this: if I am a passenger and am awaiting a bus on a bus station, there is a huge monitor on which I can see the bus code and the time it will take for him to get to my station. The problem is, that in two years of having the software, not once have I seen that the time of the arrival is even remotley accurate. I am aware that GPS data can be inaccurate but this.... And that makes me so frustrated, that I decided that I will try to write a similar application for my final exam in CS in college. The problem is that I searched the web extensively in the last few days, and I cannot find good starting points. So my question is: have you ever been involved in such a project, and if so could you give me some pointers be it tutorials, or books regarding the subject? I appreciate any kind of input.
If I made a mistake regarding the question itself feel free to close it.
Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it's the accuracy of the GPS location that causes the problem, more that the time to get from A to B is highly variable depending on traffic etc.

Comment: @Vicky yes, I took that into consideration, and I agree. But it can't be all the time. I had in mind of making sort of a simulation based on Open Street Map, and maybe to program it in  way that it would take into account the one minute delay on traffic lights....?

Comment: You can correct the estimated TOA every time it passes a stop though, so it shouldn't be too inaccurate.

Comment: @Nebbs, I agree with Vicky here: GPS is generally accurate to within a few hundred feet, which is not sufficient to cause big errors. Predicting transit times is much more challenging. A more subtle, but realistic, source of error would be if transmission of GPS data from the buses or from the server to the stations was consistently delayed but unaccounted for.

Comment: @Richard yeah, I agree too, probably there is some sort of a lag between the server and the buses. I tried to make a small ad hoc model at work today, and I'm guessing that time is going to be the key factor here just like you said. Also I will have to consult with my teacher about the Kalman and Markov. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably have:

- Vehicle object containing each vehicles position, assigned route, direction of travel on route, and next scheduled stop, previous scheduled stop, arrival time at previous scheduled stop
- Array of routes which comprises a list of stops and a data structure holding historic transit times between stops on each route

Now, updates to a vehicle's location push to the vehicle's object.

When you want to update a display at a station, find all routes passing through that station and for each route display the estimated arrival time of the next vehicle on that route.

The estimated arrival time structure is at the heart of this. Seed it by assuming some distance between stops and an average travel speed.

Now, every time a vehicle arrives at a stop, calculate the real time it took to get there from its last stop and use this to update an average transit time binned by half-hour increments (or what have you), you could also bin by season and/or day of week. The purpose of the binning is to implicitly account for varying traffic congestion by time of day, day of week, and/or season. Assuming otherwise homogeneous conditions, you'll eventually converge on a decent estimate of the transit time between each station.

You may find it useful to employ a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

Estimates of travel times between more distant stations may be more accurate than travel times between adjacent stations, if you feel like looking into that. Higher-order [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) may also help describe the underlying statistics of transit times.

Just ideas.

Comment: wow thank you very much for such a good and fast answer! I didn't account for the traffic jams during the summer for example when tourist are in town. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, @Nebbs. You may also find that you have better predictive success by averaging your vehicle's trips between more distant, rather than adjacent, stations. You could also look into higher-order [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). It may take some experimentation to get it right.

Comment: @AlexWien, the Kalman filter would be used in updating bins corresponding to interstation transit times under particular conditions. This assumes some kind of "true" average transit time with noise in the form of traffic conditions which vary about a mean for the particular bin.

Comment: @Nebbs, if this answered your question or was the most helpful answer to you, you should consider marking it as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: @Richard sorry for not doing it sooner. :)